# How do you reference the BASIC values when deploying an Azure Portal template?

Tags: azure

When you deploy a template, there are three "BASICS" settings that you have to supply.
How do you reference these values in the ARM template?
I've had to add another parameter called `location` in order to have a referenceable value.
The closest I've found via the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions is the deployment functions which shows a "location" as part of the output but this doesn't work when defining template variables.

`"variables": {"BasicsLocation": "[deployment().location]" }  /* doesn't work */`

I'm trying to avoid asking for `location` twice. 
Here is a screen snip:

[image: Azure Portal Deploy Template Blade]

Answer (score 1):

Location in Basics is a read only value based off the resource group.
To reference its value in an ARM template use the following.

"location": "[resourceGroup().location]",

The reason this value is selectable initially is to support the case where you create a new resource group as part of the deployment.  Here is the full list of BASICS values mapped as strings into template variables.

```
"variables": {
    "BasicsSubscription":  "[subscription().displayName]",
    "BasicsResourceGroup": "[resourcegroup().name]",
    "BasicsLocation":      "[resourceGroup().location]"
},
```